# jquery.load("something.php") not working well

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a `something.php` which will print the option of `dropdownlist`,\

then i load the `.php` file with

```
$("#dropdownlist").load("something.php");
```

after i load, the output is displayed, but when i change the selected value, in debug mode i din not saw a `selected="selected"` on the option of `dropdownlist` and i cannot set a `selectedvalue` to the `dropdownlist` also with

```
$("#dropdownlist").val("2");
```

any one know why this happen and how can i solve it?

## add-on code

--print option on `.php`--

```
while (isset($StatusArr[$loopCount])) {
if ($loopCount == 0) {
    $selected = "selected='true'";
} else {
    $selected = "";
}

echo "<option value='"
. $StatusArr[$loopCount][0]
. "' "
. $selected
. " >"
. $StatusArr[$loopCount][1]
. "</option>";

$loopCount ++;
}
```

---call in `.js`----

```
$('#select').load("../something.php", function (respond, fstatus, xhr) {
    if (fstatus === "success") {
        if (status !== "missing") {
            $('#status').prop("selectedIndex", 3);                
        }
    } else {
        alert("Load data " + fstatus + "\n" + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want to set the 2nd option of the dropdownlist to be selected using jQuery? Can you show how the html code of the dropdownlist looks like?

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#dropdownlist").prop("selectedIndex", 1);
```

This jQuery code sets the selected option of the dropdownlist to the 2nd option.

Comment: cannot, it still not able to set